# matlab least squares random sample generation

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am looking for some help in generating a noisy random data set with 600 samples. 
Currently I am using following code:

```
weight = randn(size,1);
noise = randn(size,1);
X = randn(size);
y = (X'*weight) + noise;
```

Weight is just a vector ∈ R. I need 600 samples that are split into one set of size 500 and another one of size 100. Help Please?
Later I will be computing mean squared error on these sets but this should be a lot easier.

Comment: Didn't the source of this code provide some explanation to what it does?

Comment: Its the code that I wrote and it doesn't work in the way it should.

Comment: OK. What is the way that it should work? How does it work instead?

Comment: it doesn't seem right, and secondly I am not too sure whether I am doing it correctly. I am trying to generate two sets (learning set and test set). I am using y = X'*weight + noise equation but I have problem with generating 600 samples and splitting it into 100 and 500 sets

Comment: If you watch closely, you'll find that you didn't answer my question at all. What did you expect to get (as in: what `size`?), and what did you get instead (what `size`?)? How have you tried splitting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggested `size = 600` if you need 600 samples.

I don't understand what for  do you use `randn` for three times with multiplication and sum (maybe you want some special distribution) but - You want noise signal, so you get it: you can check it by using `autocorr` function for `y`:
[image]

To divide your sample in two of different size use this:

```
y1 = y(1:100);
y2 = y(101:600);
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: Basically I am trying to generate a data set to analyse later. I have an equation y(i) = (x(i)^T * w) + n(i). x, w and n are using randn to generate vector/matrix. Overall I need to generate set with 600 sample which are slit into test set and training set